# Expanded variable inside another expanded variable via

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables, expansion

Is there any way to insert one expanded variable into another expanded variable, via variable substitution, within a batch file? For example...

Assuming 2 files (fileone.dll and filetwo.dll) in the following scenario:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=" %%a in ('dir "c:\users\default\desktop\*.dll" /b') do @(
 set var1=%%a
 set var2=%%b
 set var1=!var1:.dll=!var2!.dll!
)
```

This way, instead of !var1! being set to fileone.dll it would be fileonefiletwo.dll. Does that make sense?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `%%b` and so `var2` will be empty every time. You have no second token with `"delims="`

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there any way to insert one expanded variable into another expanded variable, via variable substitution, within a batch file?* ...

> - *`%%b` and so `var2` will be empty every time. You have no second token with `"delims="`*  – **[@Sephan](https://superuser.com/users/217811/stephan)**

Your question is using a `for` loop, selecting tokens 1 and 2 that are not clearly defined (see the **[@Sephan](https://superuser.com/users/217811/stephan)** comment), where their delimiters are removed (`"tokens=1,2 delims="`), and their substring is defined in each loop, considering that you have 2 files in your folder, your current loop is doing what your code is commanding:

- Your `for` in the first loop is using only the first file name listed, this being file  ***`fileone.dll`***:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=" %%a in ('dir "c:\users\default\desktop\*.dll" /b') do @(
 
 set var1=%%a is the same == > set var1=fileone.dll == > set var1=first output file name.ext in loop

 set var2=%%b is the same == > set var2= n o t h i n g == > removes a var2 that has not even been defined

 set var1=!var1:.dll=!var2!.dll! == > set var1=var1:replace_string=to_string == > set var1=fileone:.dll=.dll  == > set var1=fileone.dll

)
```

- Your `for` in the second loop is using only the second file name listed, this being file ***`filetwo.dll`***:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=" %%a in ('dir "c:\users\default\desktop\*.dll" /b') do @(
 
 set var1=%%a is the same == > set var1=filetwo.dll == > set var1=second output file name.ext in loop

 set var2=%%b is the same == > set var2= n o t h i n g == > removes a var2 that has not even been defined

 set var1=!var1:.dll=!var2!.dll! == > set var1=var1:replace_string=to_string == > set var1=filetwo:.dll=.dll  == > set var1=filetwo.dll

)
```

---

A suggestion considering your scenario and the desired substring:

> *Assuming 2 files (fileone.dll and filetwo.dll) in the following scenario:*
>
> - *This way, instead of !var1! being set to fileone.dll*

```
@echo off 

for /f %%a in ('dir "c:\users\default\desktop\*.dll" /b'
)do if not defined var1 (set "var1=%%~a")else set "var2=%%~a"

echo. & echo. var1 and var2: var1 == %var1% - var2 == %var2%
echo. & echo= set substring: set "var1=!var1:.dll=%%var2%%.dll!"

echo. & cmd /v:on /c set "var1=!var1:.dll=%var2%.dll!"
echo= var1 and var2 expanded: var1 == %var1% - var2 == %var2%
```

---

- Output/Results:

```
 var1 and var2: var1 == fileone.dll - var2 == filetwo.dll

 set substring: set "var1=!var1:.dll=%var2%.dll!"

 var1 and var2 expanded: var1 == fileone.dll - var2 == filetwo.dll
```

---

- Use *delayed expansion* when you need it to have an effect on your variable, otherwise your substring will not make sense.

```
cmd /v:on Expand variables at execution time rather than at parse time.

echo. & cmd /v:on /c set "var1=!var1:.dll=%var2%.dll!"
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)
- [`If ()Else IF () Else ()`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- `CMD /V:on|off /E:on|off ... /?`
- [Variable and Substring Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)
- [How do `SETLOCAL` and `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` work? | Refer: **`CMD /:ON /C`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18464353/8177207)

Answer (score 0):

You could do by using the second expansion mechanism that is enabled by
[EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

The below script is an example, which I put inside the file named `test.bat`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set first=second
set second=third
set var1=!%first%!
echo !var1!
```

Here is the proof of concept:

[image]

You could find more examples in the post
[How to expand a CMD shell variable twice (recursively)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199931/how-to-expand-a-cmd-shell-variable-twice-recursively).